# Foreign key not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm working on a quiz website.

There is a table called quiz which is as follows -

```
CREATE TABLE `quiz`(
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`quizname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`timeinmins` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `quizname`(`quizname`)
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then there is a table for questions which is as follows -

```
CREATE TABLE `question`(
`qtnid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`quizid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`qtext` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`quizid`, `qtnid`),
CONSTRAINT fk_quiz FOREIGN KEY (`quizid`) REFERENCES quiz(`id`)
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Inspite of `quizid` in the second table being a foreign key, it is still accepting rows without corresponding reference in the 1st table quz which is wrong as each question has to be associated with some quiz

pls help?

Comment: MyISAM does not enforce foreign keys.

Comment: Please read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Google your title. Read the manual pages that mention FKs.

Answer (score 1):

> For storage engines that do not support foreign keys (such as MyISAM),
>   MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications.

from [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

also, [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) shows an overview of the MyISAM Storage Engine's features.